# What's the difference between the "indicativo imperfetto" and the "passato remoto"?

Tags: verbs, difference, past-tense

In my native language (Dutch), there is no difference between these two forms."Parlavo" and "parlai" both mean "I spoke". I think in most languages there is only one form for expressing something that happened in the past.

What's the difference between the two forms and why does it appear only in Italian (?). When do I have to use the first form and when the second (examples please)?

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE!

Comment: Thank! I know how to speak Italian rather well because my late father was Italian. I met him in Austria though, so I spoke German with him most of the time. But because of him, I visited his birth island Ischia and worked two seasons on the beach, which forced me to learn Italian. My user name (in Dutch) means "Il Guercino", after the Italian painter whose real name was Francesco Barbieri, just like my father's name!

Comment: Keep in mind that in Italian there is also a third, very important past tense: passato prossimo. So, different aspects of the action may correspiond to _parlai_, _parlavo_ or _ho parlato_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this article by Columbia University](http://www.columbia.edu/itc/italian/resources/italiansite/GRAMMAR/IMPERFETTO/IMPERF.-REGOLE1.htm) about the *imperfetto* you can read:

> L’IMPERFETTO
>
> Come il passato prossimo, l’imperfetto esprime azioni o eventi
>   accaduti NEL PASSATO. Tuttavia l’imperfetto coglie aspetti diversi:
>
> I. Aspetto abituale.  Il verbo all’imperfetto esprime UN’AZIONE O UN
>   EVENTO CHE SI RIPETEVANO abitualmente nel passato: questi sono sentiti
>   come “vaghi” nel tempo, nel senso che NON SONO PRECISATI NEL LORO
>   INIZIO, FINE O DURATA. Spesso il verbo è accompagnato da espressioni
>   di tempo come “tutti i giorni”, “d’abitudine”, “ogni estate”,
>   “sempre”, “di solito”, ecc.
>
> 1. Andavo a trovarlo all’ospedale ogni giorno.
> 2. D’estate andavamo sempre al mare.
> 3. Da giovane facevo molto sport.
> 4. Adesso non fumo, ma prima fumavo moltissimo.
>
> II. Aspetto descrittivo. Il verbo all’imperfetto è usato per
>   DESCRIVERE un oggetto o una persona, oppure uno stato di cose, un
>   sentimento, una condizone, ecc. È particolarmente frequente all’inizio
>   dei racconti, cronache giornalistiche, favole, ecc. per descrivere la
>   situazione di “background”, cioè di sfondo.
>
> 1. L’uomo era alto e magro e aveva un folta barba.
> 2. C’era una volta una bambina che si chiamava Cappuccetto Rosso...
> 3. Durante la guerra il pane era razionato: si mangiava poco.
> 4. Mio nonno faceva il falegname [carpenter] ed era molto bravo nel suo
>      lavoro.
>
> III.   Aspetto continuativo.  Il verbo all’imperfetto coglie l’azione
>   o l’evento al passato nella continuità ininterrotta del suo
>   svolgimento, lasciando vaghi e imprecisati l’inizio e la fine. Spesso
>   questo imperfetto funziona da “background”, cioè da sfondo, a
>   un’azione “puntuale” espressa da un passato prossimo.
>
> 1. Mentre camminavo, ho visto una macchina investire un cane.
> 2. Mentre stavamo cenando, è arrivato lo zio.
> 3. Quando hai telefonato, io stavo pranzando.
> 4. Quando sono uscita, pioveva.

About *[passato remoto](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/indicativo-passato-remoto_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/)*, from Treccani, you can read:

> PASSATO REMOTO, INDICATIVO
>
> Il passato remoto (o perfetto semplice) è un tempo verbale
>   dell’indicativo e si usa per indicare un fatto avvenuto nel passato,
>   concluso e senza legami di nessun tipo con il presente; la lontananza
>   è di carattere sia cronologico, sia psicologico.
>
> Nell’uso comune può corrispondere a un distacco emotivo rispetto
>   all’evento raccontato, mentre nello scritto letterario l’uso del
>   passato remoto risponde a una scelta stilistica
>
> *Il cantante Carlo Broschi, detto Farinelli, nacque ad Andria il 24
>   gennaio 1705*
>
> *Le antiche mura perimetrali di Padova furono demolite durante la
>   guerra contro la Lega di Cambrai*
>
> *Alice trattenne il fiato mentre si sfilava la canottiera e non poté
>   fare a meno di strizzare gli occhi per un momento* (P. Giordano, La
>   solitudine dei numeri primi)
>
> Dal punto di vista della forma, alcuni verbi formano il passato remoto
>   in modo regolare (passato remoto debole) aggiungendo alla radice
>   verbale le desinenze proprie di questo tempo.

And again:

> il passato remoto è la forma del passato percepito come
>   psicologicamente lontano.

So *passato remoto* form indicates an action in the past which is finished and has no link to the present. The *imperfetto* form indicates something which happened usually in the past or with a continuous aspect.

Comment: Grazie abarisone per prendere il tempo per me e per dare una risposta!! E multo chiaro adesso.

Answer (score -1):

We have this sort of distinction between two different types of past: one that still has an impact on the present and one that doesn't. Passato remoto is used in storytelling or on something that happened a long time ago. Imperfetto is used to talk about what happened yesterday. That's basically the difference. There are some exception, for example in south Italy, people often use passato remoto instead of imperfetto even when they talk about something that didn't happen remotely in the past.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @Lorenzo! Are you maybe confusing "imperfetto" with "passato prossimo"?